# uicollectionview shifts down after updating frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am currently working on making a layout like a calendar. The basic idea is to add an `UILabel` and `UICollectionView` inside an `UIScrollView`, I am using just an `UIViewController` for layout(but with `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` delegate).

The scenario is: everytime a user searches data for a particular month(by clicking a button), the corresponding data would be given from the server and the UICollectionView frame would be set.

However, after I tried to update the frame of my `UICollectionView`, it happens that the collectionview will shift down in the `UIScrollView`, and I have no idea why this is happening. Have tried to set `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to 0 and used the `[collectionView setContentInset]` method, but it seems like not working out. Couldn't be more appreciate if anyone can give me some hint about this problem !

Below is some part of my code.

```
// viewDidLoad

    self.weekLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y, self.calendarWidth, 20)];
    self.calendarWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 7 / 4;
    self.flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y + 20, self.calendarWidth, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.weekLabel.frame.size.height * 7) collectionViewLayout:self.flowLayout];

    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell"];
    [self.collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:241/255.0f green:239/255.0f blue:228/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];

    // setup scrollView
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.collectionView.bounds.size];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.collectionView];




-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(self.calendarWidth/7, (self.scrollView.frame.size.height - 40)/5);
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.currentMonthRange == 28 && self.selectedMonth == 2) {
        return 28;
    } else if ((self.currentMonthRange + self.currentWeekDay) > 35) {
        return 42;
    } else {
        return 35;
    }
}


// method that is called after getting data from server, update the frame
-(void) checkSpecialDay {
    if (self.currentMonthRange == 28 && self.selectedMonth == 2) {
        [self.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y + 20, self.calendarWidth, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.weekLabel.frame.size.height * 3)];
    } else if ((self.currentMonthRange + self.currentWeekDay) > 35) {
        [self.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y + 20, self.calendarWidth, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.weekLabel.frame.size.height * 3)];
    } else {
        [self.collectionView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y + 20, self.calendarWidth, self.scrollView.frame.size.height - self.weekLabel.frame.size.height * 7)];
    }

    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

[Update] - Solved.

Thanks to @Adeel that the real problem is assigning the frame of my collectionview to the "frame" of the uiscrollview, instead the bug is solved after I set it to the "bounds" of the uiscrollview. But WHY is the UIScrollView's frame changed after getting any data ?

[image: before sifting]

[image: after shifting]

Comment: what is the frame of `scrollView` in `checkSpecialDay` method? Also check its `contentOffset` there.

Comment: Have to say Thank you so much @Adeel !!
Suddenly I realized that the frame of scrollView would be changed, instead I set the frame of collectionView to the bounds of the scrollView and it's all fine now !!

Comment: Mention not. Hope you'll be able to fix the problem now.